# Modifying A Two-Word String Function To Take **kwargs in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, split, boolean

I've written a basic function that takes any two-word string passed as an argument, checks that the index of both words match and returns True, otherwise False.

```
def alliteration_check(str):

    sp1, sp2 = str.split()

    if sp1[0].upper() == sp2[0].upper():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to change the param of str here to take in **kwargs? I've only recently learned about this concept so trying to understand how I can put it into practice.

Essentially, my intended function output would be that a user can place as many words as an argument and it only returns True if ALL first indexes of each string match. I'm just not sure how to write the function or if it is even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't name a variable (including a parameter) `str`, because it'll shadow the builtin `str` function/type!  You can use `str` as a type annotation, but it should come **after** the name of the parameter, eg `foo: str`.

The idea of `**kwargs` is for your function to be able to take an arbitrary set of keyword arguments (not position arguments).  Inside the implementation of the function, the arguments are available as a `dict`.

```
def alliteration_check(**kwargs: str) -> bool:
    for s in kwargs.values():
        w1, w2 = s.split()
        if w1[0].upper() != w2[0].upper():
            return False
    return True
```

You need to call this function with keyword arguments, like this:

```
alliteration_check(thing1="zig zag", other_thing="awkward alligator")
```

If you want the user to be able to call the function with an arbitrary number of *positional* arguments rather than *keyword* arguments, use `*args`:

```
def alliteration_check(*args: str) -> bool:
    for s in args:
        w1, w2 = s.split()
        if w1[0].upper() != w2[0].upper():
            return False
    return True
```

```
alliteration_check("zig zag", "awkward alligator")
```

You can also combine both of them (i.e. have a function that takes both `*args` and `**kwargs`) to be able to handle arguments in either syntax:

```
def alliteration_check(*args: str, **kwargs: str) -> bool:
    for s in (*args, *kwargs.values()):
        w1, w2 = s.split()
        if w1[0].upper() != w2[0].upper():
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer! I've not learnt about -> bool yet so I'm going to try to piece the code line by line to understand what it's doing. Thank you for the correction on not using str as a var or param, I shall note this for future ref!

Comment: The `-> bool` is a type annotation meaning "this function returns a `bool`".  It's a useful way to indicate to people reading the code (and also tools like `mypy`) how you're supposed to use the function and what it's expected to do.

Answer (score 1):

It might be more appropriate to use *args - a non-key worded, variable-length argument list - in your case because you want to check a variable number of words. Then you can iterate this like a list.

In your case you just want to check the first letter of each word is the same case-insensitive. I would build a set and check it only contains one element:

```
def alliteration_check(*args):
    return len(set(s[0].upper() for s in args)) == 1
```

You would use it like this:

```
print(alliteration_check("hello", "Hello", "hi"))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def alliteration_check(*args):
    initialWord = args[0]
    allEqual=true
    for word in args:
       if (word != initialWord):
           allEqual=false
           break
    return allEqual

alliteration_check("4", "5")
alliteration_check("10", "9")
alliteration_check('2', "3", "4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I got. For your specific situation you should be using *args not **kwargs

```
def alliteration_check(*args):
    allit = True
    for arg in args:
        if arg[0].upper() != args[(args.index(arg))-1][0].upper():
            allit = False

    return allit
```

basically this checks every argument entered into the function to the previous one and makes sure that the first letter in all of those is the same. If at any point it is not equal it changes the allit variable to false and breaks out of the loop.